# How do I import an addon in the Io language?

Tags: import, iolanguage

Specifically, I'm trying to use the Random addon.  The documentation states addons should be loaded upon first use, which is also supported by [Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.wikidot.com/small)  However, I get (running one of the sample programs)

```
Exception: Object does not respond to 'Random'
---------
Object Random                        Cards.io 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the macports installation of IO.  Building and installing from source worked (with io_static - 'io' has dylib problems)

Comment: You do need to make install for the dylib paths to be resolved properly on OSX.